# Windows Firewall state different between Powershell output and GUI

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall, windows-server-2012

When I run 
*Get-NetFirewallProfile*
I see that the Domain profile Enabled is set to True.  However, when I go to Control Panel > Windows Firewall the Domain profile is turned off by the GPO.  Also, in Windows Firewall with Advanced Settings, the Firewall state is "Off".

I'm not sure why the powershell output is different than the GUI.  Please help!

Thanks,
aB

Comment: Could you please supply some more information? What network profile is associated with active network connection? Which network profiles does the GPO touch. What  is the output of `Get-NetFirewallProfile | select Name, Enabled`?

Comment: Just tested it here at W2012 server with GPO, confirmed. Probably a bug. `Enabled` is true, control panel says GPO-disabled.

Comment: Did a tad of research, it says there's an [`Open-NetGPO`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554879%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) cmdlet that you can use to retrieve GPOs, including the resultant policy set, but I can't make it work in my environment. Maybe there's more requirements than just having a WS2012 to run the cmdlet. If you will be able to retrieve the RSOP object, feed it to `Get-NetFirewallProfile -GPOsession $rsop` and check results.

Comment: In newer PowerShell versions (tested on v5.1+) you can specify the store; i.e.: `Get-NetfirewallProfile -PolicyStore ActiveStore` will show you the current, active, merged info, as shown in the GUI.

Comment: @techie007 Nice find! You would think "ActiveStore" would be the default. I spent over an hour trying to figure out why these did not match. Also, the fact that -PolicyStore isn't an enumeration, so you can't TAB through possible values, is infuriating.

Answer (score 2):

According to this article:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4d8678e2-5653-4fd2-b275-62e0e7008ff9/conflicting-display-of-windows-firewall-setting-from-gui-and-netsh-advfirewall?forum=winserverGP

There are 2 stores for this setting, a local and a Group Policy store. A resulting firewall state is calculated based on these 2.

The answer from Elytis Cheng:

> Windows Firewall has mutliple configuration stores. One is for Group
>   Policy and one is for local. The policy that is actually applied is a
>   result of a merge of these stores (how they are merged depends on what
>   options are set in Group Policy). In Group Policy, the firewall was
>   enabled for the domain profile. However, in the local store, the
>   firewall was disabled for the domain profile. The merge result meant
>   that the firewall was on. This is shown correctly by the Control Panel
>   (which shows the active policy, not policy from a specific store). At
>   the time, the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security snap-in
>   connected to the local computer was showing the local store.
>
> The final piece is netsh. netsh firewall show allprofiles shows the
>   configuration in the local store.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Firewall Control Panel shows merged values from Group Policy and local policy. By default, `Get-NetFirewallProfile` is only viewing local values and will thus not account for any Group Policy settings.

You can view the merged settings as follows:

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile -PolicyStore ActiveStore
```

The reference for [PolicyStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/get-netfirewallprofile?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-policystore) gives the key info:

> ActiveStore: This store contains the currently active policy, which is the sum of all policy stores that apply to the computer.

For even more information, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/rules#local-policy-merge-and-application-rules